# How to properly apply a css hack for IE11 transition misbehaviour

Tags: css-position, css-transitions, internet-explorer-11, revolution-slider

I am experiencing elements transition misbehaviour into my page, IE(11) only;

The fullscreen revolution slider, remain in place doesn't move with the `wrapper` when the left slider is opening (clicking on info+ button like we have in Chrome/Firefox). Thanks to @afelixj, I've tried to use [this css hack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30962845/4642215) for IE in order to apply the tansition effect to the fullscreen slider too, adding `.fullscreen-container` but without result.

```
@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) {
  .header, #bar-left, .fullscreen-container{
      left: 0;
      transition: all .5s;
  }
  .shiftnav-open .header, .shiftnav-open #bar-left, .shiftnav-open .fullscreen-container{
     left:590px;
  }
}
```

For comparation, please open this page in IE11 and Chrome and open/close the left slider using the info+ button.Live link [here](http://goo.gl/IU1SXV)

Other non fullscreen rev sliders pages work fine using the left slider open/close in IE11/Chrome.
live link [here](http://goo.gl/gWM6mi).
Any thoughts?

LE: also I've tried to aaply to the `#wrapper` or `.shiftnav-wrapper`:

```
@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) {
  #wrapper{
      left: 0;
      transition: all .5s;
  }
  .shiftnav-open #wrapper{
     left:590px;
  }
}
```

(In this second test, the result looks ok in fullscreen rev slider pages but if I open a non-fullscreen rev slider page, the content will be shifted with +590px over 590px. when the left slider is open).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the `.fullscreen-container`, can you try to apply the style to `.forcefullwidth_wrapper_tp_banner` class?

Comment: That's it ! honestly Sir, u're the best, special thanks ! Kind regards,

Comment: Hello Sir, by chance, any hints on [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51678230/how-to-properly-achieve-a-fixed-header-position)? Thanks